# How to communicate between an ASP.net page and JSP page

Tags: asp.net, jsp

We recently had a test case where we were required to communicate between an ASP.net page and a JSP page.

The JSP page had some controls (a DataBound checkbox,TextBox etc) and the ASP.net page was supposed to manipulate those fields and pass on input values to the page.

Has any one out there encountered a similar situation, or any idea on how to implement it ?

P.S - (if required) please ask for more details, to make my question clearer.

Comment: Refer this picture for the test case - http://bit.ly/kzouMe

Answer (score 0):

You could probably send the data as URL parameters or through HTTP post, though i haven't tried this.

Another option would be to stick the data in a cookie and retrieve it at the JSP page.

Are the pages on the same domain?

Comment: The two websites are in different domains, the ASP.net website is ours, while the JSP website is purely third-party.

Comment: You can code the app to allow cross domain cookies.  I would probably try and pass the data through the URL params or http POST.  Use a page <form...> and when the user presses the submit button it POSTs form values to the JSP page.